# Error with thinking about shortest distance between two lines in three space

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given the vector equations for two lines
$$(x_0,y_0,z_0) = (a,b,c)+t(d,e,f)$$ and
$$(x_1,y_1,z_1) = (g, h, i) + t(j, k, l),$$

why is the shortest distance between the two lines not equal to
$$\dfrac{\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} g - a & h - b & i - c \\ d & e & f \\ j & k & l \end{bmatrix}\right)}{||(d,e,f)\times(j,k,l)||}?$$

My thinking was that this would be the same as taking a parallelopiped's volume and dividing by the area of the base, thus giving the height (the distance between the two lines). However, I tried this out with a couple examples and my answers differed from the actual results.

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning.

Comment: @Jared We know that volume = lwh. We also know that volume = determinant(matrix formed by 3 vectors). We then recall that the magnitude of the cross product is the area of the parallelogram formed by the vectors we cross. So, the height, given by determinant/cross product, should be the distance between the two lines.

Comment: But what does that have to do with the shortest distance between two lines?  I don't see how you turn a seemingly two dimensional problem into a three dimensional problem.

Comment: @Jared See my edited comment

Comment: The area/volume given by a determinant is assumed to be from the origin.  What in the instance of two lines is similar to an origin?

Comment: @Jared The corner of the parallelapiped formed by the two lines and the vector formed from the point on one line to the point on the other.

Comment: For me there is an asymmetry in your solution.  Can you provide an analogue for a 2D problem or a 4D problem?

Answer (score 0):

You formula is correct. What is the counter example?

Comment: I tried it out, and I got a different answer than this website for every example: http://easycalculation.com/analytical/shortest-distance-between-lines.php I was trying to write a calculator program for the TI-84 to do this, and my program gave a different answer than the website. The program implemented the method I described in my post.

Comment: Could you try taking a look at the website and let me know whether it is giving you different results?